# XPath select descendent of parents sibling with in limits

Tags: php, xpath

My xpath:
 (//tr[td[contains(., 'Refine by Vehicle Types')]])[1] /following-sibling::tr /td/div/table /tr/td/font /ul/li/a

My source:

```
<tr><td><font color="White">Refine by Vehicle Types</font></td> </tr>
<tr><td><div>
  <table> <tr> <td><font<ul><li><a> Automobile/Light Trucks</a></li></ul></font></td> </tr> </table>
</div></td> </tr>
<tr> <td></td> </tr>
<tr> <td><font>Refine by Category</font></td> </tr>
<tr> <td><div>
  <table> <tr> <td><font><ul><li><a>Agricultural</a></li></ul></font></td></tr>
```

I'm trying to scrape this source and collect the `<li>` nodes after "Refine by Vehicle Types" but not after "Refine by Category".

Any help is appriciated.

Comment: Edited your formatting. Also, it was good that you showed the XML input, and showed what you have tried; it would be even better if you would tell what the result of your attempt was.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there.

**Change**:

```
   (//tr
      [td[contains(., 'Refine by Vehicle Types')]]
    )
     [1]
      /following-sibling::tr
        /td/div/table
                 /tr/td/font
                         /ul/li/a
```

**to**:

```
   (//tr
      [td[contains(., 'Refine by Vehicle Types')]]
    )
     [1]
      /following-sibling::tr[1]
        /td/div/table
                 /tr/td/font
                         /ul/li/a
```

**When the second XPath expression is evaluated against the following XML document** (your severely malformed text corrected to become a well-formed XML document):

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
     <font color="White">Refine by Vehicle Types</font>
  </td>
</tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <table>
           <tr>
             <td>
               <font>
                  <ul>
                     <li>
                        <a> Automobile/Light Trucks</a>
                     </li>
                  </ul>
               </font>
             </td>
           </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <font>Refine by Category</font>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <font>
                <ul>
                  <li><a>Agricultural</a></li>
                </ul>
              </font>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Only one  --  the wanted -- `a` element is selected**:

```
<a> Automobile/Light Trucks</a>
```

**Note**: Did I mention that an **[XPath Visualizer](http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html)** will help you a lot?

Comment: Useful in some cases, but what if there is more than one `<tr>` (containing `<li>`) before 'Refine by Category'? or zero of them? That may be merely theoretical but I suspect the screen he's actually trying to scrape has more than one Vehicle Type.

Comment: @LarsH: I haven't tried to generalize this huge sample XML -- nor I sympathize with "screen-scraping". Such people typically aren't interested with generalization -- they want to grab the low-hanging fruit immediately and to immediately forget the XPath side of the problem -- this is why they come up back with questions again and again to this forum.

Answer (score 1):

For a robust XPath, which will work no matter how many tr/li elements are between the two text labels, try:

```
(//tr
  [td[contains(., 'Refine by Vehicle Types')]]
)[1]
  /following-sibling::tr[not(preceding-sibling::tr
                              [contains(., 'Refine by Category')])]
    /td/div/table
             /tr/td/font
                     /ul/li/a
```

(Borrowing from @Dimitre's formatting.)

The above is inefficient (could be O(n^2)), so if you have a long page, it could get slow.
But for moderate pages it should be fine.

Comment: Good attempt to generalize a problem, hope the OP will appreciate it, +1.

Comment: Of course! Greatly appriciated! When I get back on my laptop I will definitely be using Xpath Visualizer ;)

Comment: Maybe the html I gave got too messed up but this is what's working best for me 
`//tr [td[contains(., 'Refine by Vehicle Types')]]/following-sibling::tr[1]/td/div/table /tr/td/font/ul/li`